# Adding multiple v_lines for each facet in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe made up of an integer and two categorical variables

```
x<-sample(1:150, 100, replace=TRUE)
z<- sample(x=c("A","B"), size=100, replace=TRUE, prob=rep(1/2, 2))
w<-sample(x=c("Site1", "Site2"), size=100, replace=TRUE, prob=rep(1/2,2))
df<-cbind(x,z,w)
df<-data.frame(df)
colnames(df) <- c("Age", "Maturity", "Site")
df$x<-as.numeric(df$x)
```

I'm trying to use ggplot to make a plot of two overlapping density plots which are coloured by maturity stage, with mean vertical lines for each stage, and to be faceted by site. I used this code

```
cdat <- ddply(df, "Maturity", summarise, Agemean=mean(Age))
ggplot(df, aes(x=Age, fill=Maturity)) + geom_density(alpha=.2) + 
geom_vline(data=cdat, aes(xintercept=Agemean,  colour=Maturity),
         linetype="dashed", size=1)+
          facet_grid(Site~.)
```

I want the plot to instead have 4 vlines, 2 on each facet for the maturity stages. I looked around for an answer and found that I had to create a dataframe with the mean values, but I was only able to make it apply one unique vline to each facet.

Any help would be appreciated

P.S. Apologies for how untidy the data generation code is.

Comment: I think you forgot to use Site as a second grouping variable when calculating the mean lines you want to plot - `ddply(df, c("Site", "Maturity"), summarise...`.  For generating datasets, use `data.frame` directly rather than using an intermediate `cbind`; i.e., `data.frame(x, z, w)`.  This will avoid the issue of making all variables the same type.

Comment: @aosmith Cheers that worked perfectly. Is there a way to match the colour of the lines to the fill of the density plots? Using this code produces black lines  

   `plot1 <- ggplot(mortality, aes(x = Day.of.year, fill = Maturity)) + geom_density(alpha=.2) + facet_grid(Site~.)`  


   `plot1.vlinedata <- ddply(mortality, c("Site", "Maturity"), summarize,   daymean=mean(Day.of.year))`  


   `plot1 <- plot1 + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=daymean),  plot1.vlinedata)`  


   `plot1`   

I can get it to plot the lines as the same colour, but not as related to maturity.

Thanks

Comment: I tried specifying 
`plot1 + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=daymean),  plot1.vlinedata, colour=Maturity)`

But only got an error message

Comment: You probably need to move `colour` back inside `aes` for your vline layer.

Comment: @aosmith Thank you so much, its all working great now. Cheers for all your help, and thanks for the advice on generating the data as well